# Cannot open virtual machine after upgrading to 16.10

Tags: kvm-virtualization, 16.10, virtualization, virt-manager

I've just upgraded to 16.10 (from 16.04) and my kvm virtual machines are not able to start any more. I'm getting this error:

```
Error starting domain: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2016-10-27T14:47:58.353049Z qemu-system-x86_64: -enable-kvm: unsupported machine type
Use -machine help to list supported machines

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 90, in cb_wrapper
    callback(asyncjob, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/asyncjob.py", line 126, in tmpcb
    callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/libvirtobject.py", line 83, in newfn
    ret = fn(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/share/virt-manager/virtManager/domain.py", line 1402, in startup
    self._backend.create()
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/libvirt.py", line 1035, in create
    if ret == -1: raise libvirtError ('virDomainCreate() failed', dom=self)
libvirtError: internal error: process exited while connecting to monitor: 2016-10-27T14:47:58.353049Z qemu-system-x86_64: -enable-kvm: unsupported machine type
Use -machine help to list supported machines
```

Comment: Creating a new machine using the same disk serves as a workaround.

Comment: Please add the original command line to start the KVM node.

Comment: I'm using my vms through `virt-manager`. I just hit the play button, not sure what is the underlying command.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is what worked for me.  Running ...

```
virsh edit your-virtual-machine-name
```

which will ask what editor to use, and then show the generated XML for your virtual machine.  This section ...

```
<os>
  <type arch='x86_64' machine='pc-i440fx-vivid'>hvm</type>
  <bootmenu enable='no'/>
</os>
```

can be changed to this ...

```
<os>
  <type arch='x86_64' machine='ubuntu'>hvm</type>
  <bootmenu enable='no'/>
</os>
```

based on looking at the machine help ...

```
$ kvm-spice -machine help
Supported machines are:
ubuntu               Ubuntu 16.10 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996) (alias of pc-i440fx-yakkety)
pc-i440fx-yakkety    Ubuntu 16.10 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996) (default)
pc-i440fx-xenial     Ubuntu 16.04 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
pc-i440fx-wily       Ubuntu 15.04 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
pc-i440fx-trusty     Ubuntu 14.04 PC (i440FX + PIIX, 1996)
.
.
.
```

It looks like pc-i440fx-vivid is either no longer supported or was left out (possibly because it has reached [end-of-life](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Releases)).